# avrdude error on atmega1281

Tags: avr, avrdude

I have atmega1281 and AD-USBISP V03.6

I have compile problem write on flash
problem is

```
sudo avrdude -p m1281 -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -c stk500v2 -U flash:w:test.hex:i
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout 
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s
avrdude: Device signature = 0xffffff (retrying)
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s
avrdude: Device signature = 0xffffff (retrying)
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.01s
avrdude: Device signature = 0xffffff
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.
avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

first problem that I guessed is `stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout` 
but I don't know how to solve this problem. 
How to solve this problem and write `test.hex` on flash of avr ?

Answer (score 0):

You can select programmer type with `-c` option, for USBISP use `-c usbasb`. So try the following

```
sudo avrdude -p m1281 -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -c usbasb -U flash:w:test.hex:i
```

If it fails, add another option `-B 10` to set the clock

```
sudo avrdude -p m1281 -P /dev/ttyUSB0 -B 10 -c usbasb -U flash:w:test.hex:i
```

Read more information [here](http://www.dipmicro.com/store/USBASP2)